# Not Inserting values in Table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures, sqlcommand

I have written an Stored procedure for inserting values in the table. Please see the SP for your reference:-

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddingpagesinGrid] (@page_title       NVARCHAR(100), 
                                 @page_description NVARCHAR(max), 
                                 @meta_title       NVARCHAR(255), 
                                 @meta_keywords    NVARCHAR(255), 
                                 @meta_description NVARCHAR(1000), 
                                 @Active           BIT)
```

AS 
  BEGIN 
      SET nocount ON;

```
  BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO [tbl_pages] 
                  ([page_title], 
                   [page_description], 
                   [meta_title], 
                   [meta_keywords], 
                   [meta_description], 
                   [active]) 
      VALUES      ( @page_title, 
                    @page_description, 
                    @meta_title, 
                    @meta_keywords, 
                    @meta_description, 
                    @Active) 
  END 

  SELECT [page_title], 
         [page_description], 
         [meta_title], 
         [meta_keywords], 
         [meta_description], 
         [active] 
  FROM   tbl_pages
```

END

go

Also see the code-behind:-

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.Open();
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("AddingPagesInGrid", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@page_title", txtPageTitle.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@page_description", txtPagedesc.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meta_title", txtmetatitle.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meta_keywords", txtMetakeywords.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meta_description", ddlActiveInactive.SelectedIndex);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('User details saved sucessfully');window.location ='csrpage.aspx';", true);
    }
```

it is not working and giving me error as

"**Procedure or function 'AddingPagesInGrid' expects parameter '@page_title', which was not supplied.**"

Comment: What is the content of `txtPageTitle.Text`?

Comment: content means the datatype ?

Comment: No, the content. The value it holds.

Comment: The values is in text format

Comment: use CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forget to set your [`CommandType` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and your program thinks your `"AddingPagesInGrid"` as a  `Text` which is the default value of a `CommandType`.

Just add;

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

And use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{

}
```

And please don't use `AddWithValue` method. It may generate unexpected results sometimes. Use [`.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method or it's overloads.

Read: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: I am adding after the line,  'var cmd = new SqlCommand("AddingPagesInGrid", conn);'

Comment: now I am getting error as **Procedure or function 'AddingPagesInGrid' expects parameter '@Active', which was not supplied.**

Comment: Can you describe it please

Comment: @RahulSutar Your store procedure have a parameter called `@Active` but your `SqlCommand` doesn't.

Comment: I did it, but it is with 'AddWithValue' Can you tell me about .Add() ? how to implement that

Comment: @RahulSutar You can always read the documentation first. For example; `cmd.Parameters.Add("@page_title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPageTitle.Text;`

Comment: @RahulSutar = A simple search will provide you the Syntax!

Comment: @SonerGönül: Thanks will implement that way, a bit of question. My Active/Inactive is coming from dropdownlist and in Table it is the bit DataType. I want to set 1 for Active and 0 for Inactive. How to achieve that ?

Comment: @SonerGönül: The Active value is going 0 into the table, I want 1 to be added on Active and 0 on Inactive. My code for that is 'cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Active", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlActiveInactive.SelectedValue);'